# Note 961: Violates MISRA 2004 Advisory Rule 12.6, boolean expression required for operator: '!'

Tags: c++

This is a part of my code and I am getting a warning as mentioned in the title.

Code is

```
#define OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE     (1U)    
uint32_t tmp =6 ;
while (!(tmp & OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE))
```

Warning is

```
Note 961: Violates MISRA 2004 Advisory Rule 12.6, boolean expression required for operator: '!'
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @juanchopanza `Why am I getting this warning?` according to Mark

Comment: Because the MISRA rules say you should get a warning in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

The MISRA rule is (quoting from a [third party site](http://www.ristancase.com/html/dac/manual/3.12.02%20MISRA-C%202004%20Rules.html) which has to alter the rules for copyright reasons)

> 12.6 (adv): The operands of logical operators (&&, || and !) should be effectively Boolean. Expressions that are effectively Boolean should not be used as operands to operators other than (&&, || and !).

This means that you ned to replace the expression `tmp & OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE` with a boolean. In this case the correct way is to compare it to 0.

e.g.

```
while (!((tmp & OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE) != 0))
```

Comment: I think you might need to be careful with operator precedence here. As far as I remember, != has a higher precedence than &, so you'll end up with `!(tmp & (OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE != 0))`

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!(tmp & OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE != 0))
```

if you want to avoid the warning

Comment: Hi Wojtek, the same warning I am getting for other line of code that is  if ((strstr(flash->name, "M25P")) !=NULL) ..but still getting same warning like Warning 613: Possible use of null pointer 'flash' in left argument to operator '->'                                       I tried to check the condition with NULL but getting same warning

Comment: @Aswin - that is a different issue - we would need to see all the code using and setting flash.

Answer (score 0):

'tmp' is a 32-bit unsigned integer (uint32_t). 'OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE' is an unsigned integer. Using the '&' operator is 'and'ing the bits of these together, resulting in another unsigned integer. The MISRA rule wants you to use a boolean expresison rather than an unsigned integer expression as the parameter to the '!' operator.

To fix this you can use

```
while ( !((tmp & OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE) != 0))
```

or

```
while ( (tmp & OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE) != OMAP3_MCSPI_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE)
```